# Subjekt bestehend aus Nomen+Verb?

Tags: subject

Ich dachte bisher, dass das Subjekt entweder ein Pronomen ist oder ein Nomen; bis ich auf den folgenden Satz gestossen bin:

> Kaffee kochen gehört nicht zu meinen Aufgaben.

Ist hier "Kaffee kochen" das Subjekt? 
Das heisst es gibt tatsächlich Subjekte, die aus einem Nomen+Verb bestehen.

Comment: Kaffeekochen würde ich hier zusammenschreiben.  Subjekte können auch ganze Satzgruppen sein, zum Beispiel: *Kaffeekochen am Vormittag auf der Arbeit*, gehört nicht zu meinen Aufgaben.

Comment: @user1583209 richtig, aber das Komma ist falsch.

Comment: Das Subjekt (und auch andere Satzteile) können durchaus selbst aus Sätzte bestehen.

Comment: Bei einem Infinitiv als Subjekt können im Prinzip beliebige Ergänzungen stehen. Z. B. wäre auch folgendes korrekt: Am Nachmittag Kaffee für alle Mitarbeiter der Abteilung zu kochen gehört nicht zu meinen Aufgaben.

Comment: Könnte man vielleicht folgende Regel aufstellen? 
Immer wenn man eine Satzgruppe durch "es" oder "das" ersetzen kann, dann besteht das Subjekt aus der gesamten Satzgruppe? 
Beispiel: 
"Kaffeekochen am Vormittag auf der Arbeit, gehört nicht zu meinen Aufgaben." / Ersetzt: "Das gehört nicht zu meinen Aufgaben."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Kaffeekochen" ist hier tatsächlich das Subjekt.

Das nennt man [Substantivierung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivierung): die Bildung eines Substantivs aus einer anderen Wortart, vor allem aus Verben und Adjektiven

Comment: Alternativ: Kaffee zu kochen...

Comment: Ist dann die ganze Phrase "Kaffee zu kochen" das Subjekt?

Comment: @Wogehu ja, genau